# SPFX - Update list with a new field fails

Tags: spfx, column, deployment, spfx-extensions, elements-xml

I'm trying to deploy a new field (column) to a custom list that has been deployed using a SPFx Extension. The field gets added to the site, but it does not get added to the ContentType.

I've been following this [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package#define-upgrade-actions-for-new-version) however I'm still unsuccessful in updating the list.

I've added `elements-v2.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Field ID="{504d394b-c0a2-4937-b9ad-b9b7b9ad2ceb}"
        Name="TestField"
        DisplayName="TestField"
        Type="Text"
        Required="FALSE"
        Group="MyColumns" />
</Elements>
```

And `upgrade-actions-v2.xml`:

```
<VersionRange
    BeginVersion="2.0.0.0"
    EndVersion="2.9.9.9">
    <ApplyElementManifests>
        <ElementManifest Location="2aee3d9c-ffbe-48b4-9960-2290c09f8fa7\elements-v2.xml" />
    </ApplyElementManifests>
    <AddContentTypeField 
        ContentTypeId="0x010042D0C1C200A14B6887742B6344675C8B"
        FieldId="{504d394b-c0a2-4937-b9ad-b9b7b9ad2ceb}"
        PushDown="TRUE"/>
</VersionRange>
```

`package-solution.json` is updated accordingly:

```json
        "version": "2.0.0.3",
        "assets": {
          "elementManifests": [
            "elements.xml",
            "ClientSideInstance.xml",
            "elements-v2.xml"
          ],
          "elementFiles": [
            "schema.xml"
          ],
          "upgradeActions": [
            "upgrade-actions-v2.xml"
          ]
```

And the new column "TestField" is referenced in `schema.xml`

```
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="Namn"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Roll"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="E_x002d_mail"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Projektomr_x00e5_de"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="B_x00f6_rjar_x0020_p_x00e5__x002"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Slutar_x0020_p_x00e5__x0020_proj"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Bild"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="TestField"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
```

If I go to "Settings" -> "Site Columns" I can see that the column is added to the site

[image]

But if I go to the ContentType it looks like this:
[image]

The field is added to the site, but it's not added to the contentType. I can get it to work by removing the column "Testfield" from the site, increment the version in "package-solution.json", deploying, and upgrading app on the site. That way the "Testfield" is added to the site again but this time it's associated contentType from some reason.

To summarize the issue:
Updating the list with a new field/column fails because the field/column does not get added to the ContentType that is associated with the list.

Am I missing something in order to get the field added to the ContentType? Looking at the guides/reference for `<AddContentTypeField>` I cannot see that I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You ever got a solution for this? Or some more references? I'm trying to understand this process as well. Actually I need to update an existing field (adding a Choice to a dropdown).

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the version needs to be increased in the first 3 numbers.
The last number does not seem to trigger any upgrade actions.

2.0.0.0 --> 2.0.0.3 ==> no actions executed
2.0.0.0 --> 2.0.1.0 ==> actions are executed and column is added to type and list

The only thing I was not able to do is display it in the List View (`ViewFields`).